# Deprecation warning when trying to use isBefore on current time using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get the current timestamp, then compare it to a variable e.g. '21:00' to see if the current time is before this time.

I've added some logic using moment.js to get the timestamp, format it to HH:MM then use isBefore but it always returns false even though it should be true. I also get a deprication warning?

```
  const currentTime = moment().format('HH:MM')
  const deadline = '21:00'

  moment(currentTime).isBefore(deadline, 'hour')
```

If I log the last line it returns false when it should be true and the error I get is

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged.
```

Comment: `21:00` does not define a valid moment in one of the recognized standard formats, because it's missing the date.

Comment: The deprecation warning is pretty clear; the format is not one of the accepted formats. Why not supply a format and compare the moments? `moment().isBefore(moment(deadline, 'HH:MM'), 'hour')`